How do I change the displayed name of a theorem environment locally?
I am using a theorem environment to write definitions, with the displayed text being "Definition.", but I want to make one of these to say "Definitions." This is the code I am using.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{definition}{Definition}

\begin{document}
\begin{definition}
This is definition 1.
\end{definition}

\begin{definition} %I want it to say "Definitions" here.
This is definition 2. This is related definition 3.
\end{definition}
\end{document}


The simplest way is to define definitions.

@egreg are you suggesting that I define a separate environment for this purpose?

Yes, that's the idea. Yours can be accomplished, but in the end it will consists in more work than just adding s at the beginning and end of the environment.

I'd just go by defining
\newtheorem*{definitions}{Definitions}

Changing definition into definitions just requires adding twice an s.
A possible different strategy:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{definitioninner}{\definitionname}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{definition}{t+}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \renewcommand{\definitionname}{Definitions}%
  }{\renewcommand{\definitionname}{Definition}%
  }%
  \begin{definitioninner}%
}{\end{definitioninner}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\definitionname}{}{}% initialize

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}
This is definition 1.
\end{definition}

\begin{definition}+
This is definition 2. This is related definition 3.
\end{definition}

\end{document}


However, I find this error prone and less readable than
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem*{definitions}{Definitions}

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}
This is definition 1.
\end{definition}

\begin{definitions}
This is definition 2. This is related definition 3.
\end{definitions}

\end{document}

